# How to render a cumulative histogram based on ALA

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics

I'd like to render a cumulative histogram of the duration of various workflows.

This is the query I use to compute the duration of various workflows, and the timeElapsedInMs result can be used to do things like compute percentiles (as shown). The durations span a fairly sizable range, from under a second to several minutes. What I would like to do is render a cumulative histogram of the data. My best guess at this point is that the `accumulate` property of one of the `render` types might work, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to do that.

```
let start = fluentbit_CL
| where log_s has_cs "<starting event>"
| project  trackingId = trackingId_g, timestampStart= _timestamp_t;
let finish = fluentbit_CL
| where log_s contains "<ending event>" 
| project  trackingId = trackingId_g, timestampFinish = _timestamp_t;
start
| join finish on trackingId
| extend timeElapsedInMs = datetime_diff('millisecond', todatetime(timestampFinish ), todatetime(timestampStart))
| summarize min=min(timeElapsedInMs), avg=avg(timeElapsedInMs), percentiles_array(timeElapsedInMs, 50, 95), max=max(timeElapsedInMs)
```

I'd also be happy with another sensible way to render the data to get a look at the percentiles, but my current best approaches don't get a very clear impression of the data.

Comment: For the percentiles please open a new post

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no need to write one query for starting event and one for ending event and then join them. This can be done with a single query, using `summarize`.
2. Histogram can be easily created using `bin` ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/summarizeoperator#histogram))
3. Accumulated histogram can be easily rendered using `with (accumulate=True)` ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/renderoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer#syntax))

---

```
// This part of the code is just for data sample generation and is not part of the solution
let start = materialize (range trackingId_g from 1 to 100 step 1 | extend _timestamp_t = ago(24h * rand()), log_s = "<starting event>");
let finish = materialize (start | extend _timestamp_t = _timestamp_t + 5m * rand(), log_s = "<ending event>");
let fluentbit_CL = (union start, finish);
// The solution starts from here
fluentbit_CL
| summarize duration = anyif(_timestamp_t, log_s has_cs "<ending event>") - anyif(_timestamp_t, log_s has_cs "<starting event>")
            by trackingId_g
| summarize count() by bin(duration, 10s)
| order by duration asc
| render timechart with (accumulate=True)
```

[image]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA42RQU/DMAyF75X6H6ydWhjahuAE48IJiePuVZa6TaBJqsQBhvbjcdZtdAwkenPfs98XezaDldIBeuEJXAOkEKSrEfjfSwwEjfNQCxIQhOk7hBYtekHaWRC2Tjbr6KQ9uC4mPc86JAiUpCUYQei16PQnQuGFbRHIC/mqbftUVy003hlYADlYzOfchT1XW8APQo6pSBvkUaav0jDRuuL6RsEF8KS6KMspdK6tAkuT%2010ijwV8Q0sPk/JuIGm01UH9RBn4/go6KS/h1hwjx4nc%20FteF7lea6oen9lWRJuWtsub7mGSdZYu8L21wRCGfSj0mGfjQXm2hRCNET7R13F/Cl6J3eimGPMeCJUIlQznmHD1n6azbeYZjL715uSMp3jSRUtFmUxrbYsD7ZRPHMpkdb5Gn%20TjQ0SQSfDMykoCkyod6F2TgkJIGU3s%20H7LlY9YfgHoQuUSvgIAAA==)